# How to update variable values in ACL2?

Tags: acl2

I’m new to ACL2 theorem prover. I want to update the value of a variable based on XOR result of three variables. I think “setq” will do that for me.

```
(setq out (xor (xor a b) c))
```

However, I get this error:

> ACL2 Error in TOP-LEVEL:  The symbol SETQ (in package "COMMON-LISP") has neither a function nor macro definition in ACL2.  Moreover, this symbol is in the main Lisp package; hence, you cannot define it in ACL2.  See :DOC near-misses.  Note:  this error occurred in the context (SETQ OUT (XOR (XOR A B) C)).

Can't we use main Lisp functions in ACL2? Is there another way to update variable values in ACL2? I have already tried "assign", but I don't want my variable to become global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACL2 is an [applicative programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applicative_programming_language) (in fact ACL2 stands for "A Computational Logic for Applicative Common Lisp"), so you cannot mutate values in your code; you can only bind new ones.  So perhaps `let` or `let*` is what you're looking for.